# How can I edit the RowHeader in the DataGrid?

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid

The text box under id still belongs to the header and I would like to change the yellow marked field next to the header from this DataGrid so that it looks like the green marked field on picture 2.

**Picture1:**

[image: Picture]

**Picture2:**

[image: Picture2]

My Datagrid Xaml Code is this:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="345"  Margin="52,76,5,0" x:Name="gridd" Width="619" >

        <DataGrid.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gray"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="White"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,0,1,0" />
            </Style>

            <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Gray"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,0,1,0" />
            </Style>

            <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRowHeader}">
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="15"/>
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="20"/>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Gray"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1,1,1,1"/>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.Resources>

        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" SortMemberPath="Id" Binding="{Binding Id}" CanUserResize="False" IsReadOnly="True">
                <DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="Id" Margin="3 0 0 0" Width="148" Height="17"/>
                        <Separator Background="White" Width="125" />
                        <TextBox x:Name="IDSearcBox" Width="113" Height="19" Margin="0 0 0 2"  Text="{Binding QueryforID, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataGridTextColumn.Header>
            </DataGridTextColumn>

            <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" SortMemberPath="Id" Binding="{Binding Name}" CanUserResize="False" IsReadOnly="True">
                <DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="Name" Margin="3 0 0 0" Width="148" Height="17"/>
                        <Separator  Background="White" Width="125" />
                        <TextBox x:Name="Name" Width="113" Height="19" Margin="0 0 0 2"  Text="{Binding Queryforname, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataGridTextColumn.Header>
            </DataGridTextColumn>

            <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" SortMemberPath="Id" Binding="{Binding Country}" CanUserResize="False" IsReadOnly="True">
                <DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="Land" Margin="3 0 0 0" Width="148" Height="17"/>
                        <Separator Background="White" Width="125"/>
                        <TextBox x:Name="Birthday" Width="113" Height="19" Margin="0 0 0 2"  Text="{Binding QueryforCountry, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataGridTextColumn.Header>
            </DataGridTextColumn>


            <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" SortMemberPath="Id" Binding="{Binding Location}" CanUserResize="False" IsReadOnly="True">
                <DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="Ort" Margin="3 0 0 0" Width="148" Height="17"/>
                        <Separator Background="White" Width="125" />
                        <TextBox x:Name="Ort" Width="113" Height="19" Margin="0 0 0 2"   Text="{Binding QueryforLocation, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataGridTextColumn.Header>
            </DataGridTextColumn>


            <DataGridTextColumn SortMemberPath="Id" Binding="{Binding Age}" CanUserResize="False" IsReadOnly="True">
                <DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="Alter" Margin="0 0 0 0" Width="115" Height="17"/>
                        <Separator Background="White" Width="125"/>
                        <TextBox x:Name="alter" Width="119" Height="19" Margin="0 0 0 2" Text="{Binding QueryforAge, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataGridTextColumn.Header>
            </DataGridTextColumn>


        </DataGrid.Columns>

    </DataGrid>
```

How did I need to change the DataGrid to get this look? I think i need to change something in the DataGrid.Resources Part but I dont know how to change Picture 1 to Picture2

**Edit:**
It now look like this but the Stack Panel i createt doesnt fill the entire Fild

[image: Picture 3]

Comment: Set the desired values for the DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate and DataGrid.RowHeaderStyle properties.

Comment: can you give me an xaml snippet what solve my problem to get this look like picture 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can restyle that `Button` in the header by defining a adding a `Style` with a specific `ComponentResourceKey` key to <DataGrid.Resources>, e.g.:

```
<Style x:Key="{ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=DataGridSelectAllButtonStyle, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type DataGrid}}"
       TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Content">
        <Setter.Value>
            <TextBlock FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Text="&#xE71C;" />
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

You can set the `Content` property to whatever you want. The above `TextBlock` is just an example.

Comment: That already comes in the direction I need it, but how can I add a separator? So that it looks like the picture 2?

Comment: @Dr.rektalius: You will need add the separator to the `Content`. You could for example set the `Content` to a `StackPanel` as you have done for the headers.

Comment: I tried to place the seperator above the TextBlock and under the Setter.Value but this didnt work because i only can place 1 Setter.Value but this is the only point where i can write a seperator

Comment: You can set the `Value` of the `Setter` to a `StackPanel` as I wrote in my previous answer. You can then add several elements to the `StackPanel`.

Comment: Alright i edit my Question to show you how it looks with the Stackpanel how can i Fill the entire Field with the Stackpanel?

Answer (score 0):

A minimal example to demonstrate:

```
<DataGrid>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Mode=OneWay}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGrid.ItemsSource>
        <x:Array Type="{x:Type sys:String}">
            <sys:String>One</sys:String>
            <sys:String>Two</sys:String>
            <sys:String>Three</sys:String>
        </x:Array>
    </DataGrid.ItemsSource>
    <DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Ellipse Width="10" Height="10" Fill="Red"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>
</DataGrid>
```

Instead of Ellipse, use the Image or Shape with Geometry you need.

In the upper left corner (to the left of the Columns Headers and above the Rows Header) there is a Button with a RoutedCommand `Command =" {x: Static DataGrid.SelectAllCommand} "`.
The button gets the style from the dynamic key `Style ="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId = DataGridSelectAllButtonStyle, TypeInTargetAssembly = {x: Type DataGrid}}}"`.

Here is the complete definition of a button in the default template for DataGrid:

```
<Button Command = "{x: Static DataGrid.SelectAllCommand}"
        Focusable = "false"
        Style = "{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId = DataGridSelectAllButtonStyle, TypeInTargetAssembly = {x: Type DataGrid}}}"
        Visibility = "{Binding HeadersVisibility, ConverterParameter = {x: Static DataGridHeadersVisibility.All}, Converter = {x: Static DataGrid.HeadersVisibilityConverter}, RelativeSource = {RelativeSource AncestorType = {x: Type DataGrid}}}"
        Width = "{Binding CellsPanelHorizontalOffset, RelativeSource = {RelativeSource AncestorType = {x: Type DataGrid}}}" />
```

You can override the button style in the DataGrid resources using this key:

```
<DataGrid>
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="{ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=DataGridSelectAllButtonStyle, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type DataGrid}}">
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Ellipse Width="10" Height="10" Fill="Green"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Mode=OneWay}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGrid.ItemsSource>
        <x:Array Type="{x:Type sys:String}">
            <sys:String>One</sys:String>
            <sys:String>Two</sys:String>
            <sys:String>Three</sys:String>
        </x:Array>
    </DataGrid.ItemsSource>
    <DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Ellipse Width="10" Height="10" Fill="Red"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>
</DataGrid>
```

If you need another element instead of a Button, then for this you have to create your own template for the DataGrid.

Option for placing two elements vertically with a dividing line:

```
<DataGrid>
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="{ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=DataGridSelectAllButtonStyle, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type DataGrid}}">
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Ellipse Width="10" Height="10" Fill="Aqua"/>
                            <Rectangle Grid.Row="1" Fill="Yellow" Height="2" Margin="0 2"/>
                            <Ellipse Grid.Row="2" Width="10" Height="10" Fill="Green"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
```

Comment: This shows me points in the lower fields, but I want it to be in the top line, right next to the header.

Comment: I do not understand your explanation.
Do you need to complete the Column Header?
Give a larger screenshot of two views: as it is now and as you need it.

Comment: Seems to understand.
You need the top left corner: to the left of the Columns Headers and above the Rows Headers.

Comment: I've made changes to my answer.
Read them.